# How to load base64 png image to canvas

Tags: javascript

I need to load base64 image to canaves .I tried this code but not load base64 image,but other text and image load correctly how can i do ot?

I tried to load base64 image to canvas

```
  var playerName=document.getElementById('player-name').textContent;
  var cx = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = cx.getContext("2d");


  var playerPicture=document.getElementById('photo');

  var GoHouseSelect = new Image();

  GotHouseSelect.src="\""+GoHoueImage[imageNum]+"\""; 
  console.log(GoHouseSelect);

      ctx.drawImage(playerPicture,230,100,180,180);
      ctx.drawImage(GoHouseSelect,0,0);
      ctx.font = "56px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(playerName,200,380);
```

I have a this "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 400 (Bad Request)" error in chrome

Answer (score 0):

URI to access Base64 images is

```
data:text/<image extension>;base64,<base64 string>
```

In your case, it may look like this (assuming the image is png)

```
GotHouseSelect.src="data:text/png;base64," + GoHoueImage[imageNum];
```